# Linux basics - how to exit a running command

Tags: linux, shell, putty

After last command executed, I am not able to come back. Only it is taking characters but not terminated? 
Can you please tell me exit command, I am new for linux.
[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me exit command, I am new for linux.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your program is doing, here are a few of options:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Interrupt the running program
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: Send EOF (End Of File) to the running program, may trigger a graceful exit.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: Suspend the program. Will leave the program suspended in the background.